# error: ‘whatever class' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, g++

main contains:

```
#include "num.h"
num * intObj = new num;
```

num.h contains:

```
#ifndef __EXPR_H__
#define __EXPR_H__
#include <string>

class num : public Expr {
//
};
#endif
```

expr.h contains:

```
#ifndef __EXPR_H__
#define __EXPR_H__
#include <string>

class Expr {
 public:
  virtual int eval() const = 0;
  virtual std::string prettyPrint() const = 0;
  virtual ~Expr();
};
#endif
```

Then I get:

```
error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope
       num * intObj = new num;
         ^
```

What can be the reason for this? I have also declared the class Expr in a different .h file, which is also included in main.

I get the same error with all the new classes I declared and am using.

Comment: @old_mountain no, I'm not including expr.h in num.h .. Should I be? Also, I posted expr.h above.

Comment: Do you know what `#ifndef`/`#endif`, `#define` and `#include` do? And why the `#ifndef` statement in num.h causes the entire header to be ignored if `expr.h` was already included?

Comment: @user yes, you should.

Comment: @user -- Yes, you should be including expr.h in num.h because `class num` (which is defined in num.h) extends class `Expr` (which is defined in expr.h). Your cardinal sin however is using the same include guard in multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same header guard `__EXPR_H__` for both headers. Only one will be defined.

Change `__EXPR_H__` in `num.h` to `__NUM_H__` and it will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try one of the following:

```
#include "expr.h"  /* before num.h */
#include "num.h"
num * intObj = new num;
```

or

```
#ifndef __NUM_H__  /* Header file guard for num.h not expr.h here */
#define __NUM_H__
#include <string>
include "expr.h"  /* #ifndef __EXPR_H and #define __EXPR_H__ in this .h file */

class num : public Expr {
//
};
#endif
```

Comment: @DavidHammen, sorry I didn't understand, why wouldn't it work? Please refer to the answer which is posted by old_mountain above and is accepted as the solution.

Comment: The first option is the one that won't work. The second option is fine.

Comment: Correct, that is why I proposed two approaches.

Comment: But your first approach is incorrect. You should edit it out.